# Spark and BloomFilter sharing

Tags: apache-spark, bloom-filter

I have a huge RDD (source) and I need to create a BloomFilter data out of it, so the subsequent updates to the user's data will consider only true "diffs", no duplication.

Looks like most of the implementations of the BloomFilter are non-serializable (that could be fixed easily though), but I want slightly different workflow:

1. Process every partition and create an instance of an appropriate BloomFilter for each of the partitions. For each of those BloomFilter objects - write it into a binary file somewhere. I don't know actually how to process the partition at whole - there is `mapPartition` function available on RDD, but that expects me to return an Iterator. Perhaps I could consume the passed iterator, create an instance of BloomFilter, write it to somewhere and return the link to the create file as an `Iterator.singleton[PathToFile]`?
2. On master node - `consume` the results of that processing (list of paths to File), read those files and aggregate the BloomFilters in memory. Then write the response into a binary file.

I don't know the right way to:

- create a file in the FS supported by a cluster (it could be HDFS, S3N or local file) from within a function that is passed to `mapPartitions`
- read the content of the files in the second phase with `consume` (when I have an RDD with the paths to the files, and I have to use `SparkContext` to read them - don't see how it's possible).

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`breeze` implementation is not the fastest one but it comes with usual Spark dependencies and can be used with `simple aggregate`:

```scala
import breeze.util.BloomFilter

// Adjust values to fit your case
val numBuckets: Int = 100
val numHashFunctions: Int = 30

val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq("a", "d", "f", "e", "g", "j", "z", "k"), 4)
val bf = rdd.aggregate(new BloomFilter[String](numBuckets, numHashFunctions))(
  _ += _, _ |= _
)

bf.contains("a")
```

```
Boolean = true
```

```scala
bf.contains("n")
```

```
Boolean = false
```

In Spark 2.0+ you can use `DataFrameStatFunctions.bloomFilter`:

```scala
val df = rdd.toDF

val expectedNumItems: Long = 1000 
val fpp: Double = 0.005

val sbf = df.stat.bloomFilter($"value", expectedNumItems, fpp)

sbf.mightContain("a")
```

```
Boolean = true
```

```scala
sbf.mightContain("n")
```

```
Boolean = false
```

[`Algebird`](https://github.com/twitter/algebird) implementation works as well and can be used similarly to `breeze` implementation.

Comment: what is $"value"  in val sbf = df.stat.bloomFilter($"value", expectedNumItems, fpp)

Comment: `$"value"` is an object of class `Column` - in other words it is a column on which you want to create Bloom filter.  `$` is equivalent to `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col`  for example.

Comment: When using in spark, you will have to setup your Bloom Filter as a BroadCast variable, otherwise you will end-up with with too much per-task overhead. BroadCast variables are broadcast once per executor, otherwise, the bloomfilter will transmit once per task (or be built for every task execution).

Comment: @YoYo Unless data is reused between stages or you are worried about deserialization cost there is no good reason to broadcast filter.

Comment: Without broadcast, you end up sending potentially millions of copies of the same filter to individual tasks Through closure. The need to share between stages doubles that number. BloomFilters can grow surprisingly large in size too. With broadcast, you only send one copy to each executor, numbering maybe only in the few tens.

Comment: @YoYo Not really. Just to quote the programming guide _Spark automatically broadcasts the common data needed by tasks within each stage.  The data broadcasted this way is cached in serialized form and deserialized before running each task_.

Comment: I guess that would make sense. And your earlier statement also matches this official statement: [_Explicitly creating broadcast variables is only useful when tasks across multiple stages need the same data or when caching the data in deserialized form is important._](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables). - thanks.

Comment: Does the bf.contains("value") should exactly match with the Seq("a", "d", "f", "e", "g", "j", "z", "k") ?